# How to enable "Virtualization Technology" in Windows Server 2016 instance of google cloud?

Tags: windows, google-cloud-platform, virtualization, windows-server-2016

I can't approach to BIOS setting while I launch a google cloud instance.
Is that similar to "nested virtualization" which I keep on found 
 ( https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/enable-nested-virtualization-vm-instances? )

I tried to enable it by installing Avast and disable the "Hardware assistance accelerating", but it was checked again after I reboot.

Wish Vt was enabled and I can install HyperX. :(

Thanks for any help!

Comment: I'm not sure to help you on this topic, but I'm curious: Why performing virutalization on virtual VM? What's the use case?

Answer (score 4):

What is HyperX?

If you mean Hyper-V, then the answer is you cannot set up Hyper-V on Windows Server on Google Compute Engine.

ESX and Xen are not supported either. **Only KVM Hypervisors are supported.**

To enable nested virtualization for KVM compatible hypervisors read this document: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/enable-nested-virtualization-vm-instances